# Database Allow Duplicate Entry for Foreign Key

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two tables `users`, and `posts`. The `posts` table has a column with the foreign key `user_id` which corresponds to the `id` in the `users` table. If another row is inserted to the `posts` table and it has the same value in the `user_id` column as another row, I get an error:

> "Duplicate entry '4' for key in 'user_id'"

How can I allow for duplicate entries in this `user_id` column?

Comment: Sounds like `posts` has a unique constraint applied to `user_id`. Are you able to check and remove it?

Comment: Thats was it! I went into the relational view, edit keys, and changed it from unique, to index. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

I went into the relational view, edit keys, and changed it from unique, to index. Thanks to Cory.